# Azure data factory convert timestamp taking into account DST

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-data-factory, dst

I have a data flow in Azure Data Factory
The source contains timestamps in local time 
The sink is a SQL that is running on UTC

In the DataFlow, I can convert the timestamp to UTC using the following command

`toUTC(timestamp, "Romance Standard Time")`

But that does not take into account DST.

Is there a way to do this directly in the dataflow ?

Answer (score 2):

The `toUTC` function should indeed take into account DST, as well as other historical changes to time zone offsets.

According [to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#toutc), the supported time zones are those used by Java, which would be the regular [IANA time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (plus a few extra abbreviations for Java legacy purposes).

`"Romance Standard Time"` is a *Windows* time zone identifier.  An equivalent IANA zone that should work with ADF would be `"Europe/Paris"`.  Refer to [the CLDR mapping here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

(If you need to do this mapping in .NET code, use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.)